# Running an Android app that uses the TClientDataSet component from Delphi 10.4.1

Tags: android, delphi, tclientdataset

I am having trouble trying to test-run my FMX app which I am trying to port from Windows to Android.
After building the application successfully and with no warning or error messages the USB connected device (8.1" Huwawei Media Pad running Android 9) shows the flash PNG and freezes.

After removing all the units that use the DBClient library, my ShowMessage call worked showing the message, which assured me that the settings were OK and that something relating to DBClient was not correctly deployed on the device.

I use TClientDataSet as in-memory tables only. No database connections or transactions are executed.

I searched the internet for hints on using TClientDataSet by Delphi Android apps with no luck.

I followed Jim McKeeth's instructions on installing the Android SDK https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DXtU_8QdVE. But that was long before Delphi 10.4.1 was rolled out.

Does this have to do with the Android SDK setup? If so, what am I missing?

Thanks.

- Delphi 10.4.1 - Andriod SDK 25.2.5 - 64-bit Android apk build.

Comment: There's too much going on here that we cannot see. Start your Android development project from scratch with a blank form. At each step, add a bit of code from the original project, and make sure that it compiles and runs before you move on. Also: Delphi should install the SDK and configure the IDE for you.